# Is there a comprehensive list of every monk bonus feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, monk

I know there aren't as many as fighter bonus feats, but I discovered there are more than the ones listed in the PHB (Stunning Fist/Improved Grapple, Combat Reflexes/Reflect Arrows, Improved Disarm/Improved Trip). such as in the PHB2, where you can get Fiery Fist, Ki Blast and Fiery Ki Defense, or in the Eberron campaign guide is also Monastic Training, which you can get at either 1st, 2nd or 6th level.

Is there any way I can look for all of them or do I have to look at every single feat in every single 3.5 book to see if there is any more? Google does not help much in this aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer that I might try to work into something more complete.

- [Alternative Class Features List](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?444354-3-5-Alternative-Class-Features-(ported-from-Wizards-community-boards)) covers a lot of things, because it’s pretty comprehensive for all alternative class features, substitution levels, variant levels or features, and so on. Many monk options for feats come from such things, so that will cover many of them. It does **not** cover things like Fiery Fist or Monastic Training that are **feats** that say they can be selected by monks, but
- [This post in that same thread](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=20737569&postcount=41) **does** list many of those, and many more. I do not know how comprehensive it is.

Neither list covers monk fighting styles, which are a major source of alternative bonus feat options. There may also be other things that offer options, either other categories that aren’t covered, or things that are under the remit of one of these but has simply been missed.

Comment: Does that make the answer to the question "no"? But you're trying to link to separate off-site lists that *may* combine to have them?

Comment: @NautArch I’m not saying “no” because I don’t *know* (and certainly can’t back up) that there isn’t—this is just the best I’m aware of.

Comment: I don't know enough about 3.5, but could the question be changed to ask for the complete list here? Or is it too broad and/or other issues?

Comment: I could accept this answer if anyone could back up those lists completeness, since they are very good.

Comment: @NautArch It could be, but I don’t think there’s any *need* to—it’s pretty well-established here that when someone asks for a resource, simply providing that resource in an answer is a valid answer to the question. And I don’t think a partial answer is going to dissuade anyone inclined to do that from doing it (or from linking a better resource, if one exists).

Comment: @Karrion42 Yeah, hopefully either someone knows a better resource, or someone (and this might be me, if I get some time to do it) goes ahead and creates one (perhaps with this as a starting point). Whether you accept this as-is (and switch to one of those hypothetical answers if they happen) or not is up to you. I agree with you that without knowing how comprehensive these lists are, they aren’t as useful as they could or should be, so personally I probably wouldn’t accept it as-is.

Comment: The big deal is the approximately 20 monk fighting styles (many in *UA* but a handful in *Dragon*). Neither of those lists includes those, and the monk fighting styles (short of martial monk abuse) offer the widest variety of bonus feats for monks.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Good point, yeah, I’ll definitely look to improve upon what we have here.

Comment: It could be worth at least mentioning the Martial Monk from Dragon 310, the most poorly thought out source of additions to the list.